# How to use background thread for inline operation in android

Tags: android

I have the following program flow:

1. User fills in form
2. My app generates a number of records via a content provider which may take some time (say 10 seconds)
3. The user can then continue with the program

I have 2 questions:

1. Why use a non-UI thread to perform step 2 - given that the user can do nothing in my application until this process has been completed, why don't I just use a waiting widget?
2. If I should use a non UI thread - which type of asynchronous thread approach would make the most sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not the only one using the UI thread. For example, you will be blocking things such as the clock, notifications, etc. And after a few seconds, Android will show an ANR (application not responding dialog), asking the user if they want to wait or kill your app. As for 2, use an `AsyncTask`, it makes it easy to do your work and update the UI when done.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AsyncTask`. Look at this tutorial [AsyncTask - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Here Docum..[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask itz the answer you where searching...  Click [here](http://jimmanz.blogspot.in/2012/05/async-task-in-android.html)!